# what is Russell's Neutral Monism and how does it differ from Spinoza's Substance Monism?

Tags: metaphysics, bertrand-russell, spinoza

I have studied Spinoza, so you don't need to explain that part.
For some reason, explanations of Russell on the internet don't get into my head, that's why I've come here.

Comment: If you do not tell us which explanations you read and what exactly in them does not get into your head why would here be any different than at the rest of the internet? Have you read [SEP, Russellian Monism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/neutral-monism/#RussMoni), for example?